# How can I enable Javadoc warnings in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Is it possible in Eclipse to have the warnings displayed in the editor about Javadoc issues.
for example, I often rename / change parameters of methods and forget to update the Javadoc accordingly.

This would be great to notice that before the next Javadoc compilation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Javadoc

When renaming use the refactor option - ALT + SHIFT + R. It will automatically rename javadoc param names as well.